# Android - How to set a specific calendar inserting an event with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

```
public static void insertEventWithName(Context ctx, long id, String eventName, String descriptionEvent, Calendar beginTime) {

    intent.putExtra(Events.CALENDAR_ID, (int) id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, eventName);
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, descriptionEvent);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
    intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

In order to insert an event I use this code, but is always set last used calendar . 
I'd like to see calendar with my id

Comment: I have got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem too, @joshi737 did you find a solution ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Does anyone find the solution? @joshi737

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro Did you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding calendar name instead of its id.

```
 intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "test@gmail.com")
```

For me, it sets the specific calendar when it opens the chosen calendar application.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to call a specific calendar by calling intent `setData` as below:

```
intent.setData(buildCalUri());
```

Where buildCalUri returns the URI used for creating the specific calendar

```
public static Uri buildCalUri() {
        return CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
        .setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, APPOINTMENT_CALENDAR_NAME)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, EMAIL)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, APPOINTMENT_CALENDAR_NAME)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, getCalendarID(EMAIL, APPOINTMENT_CALENDAR_NAME));
startActivity(intent);
```

Try giving more parameters for it to distinguish. I was also facing the same issue but when I provided above details, it redirected to correct Calendar. Hope it helps.